# Which fitting do I need to run a modern fridge's 1/4" ice maker supply line to an older supply valve with a larger flare outlet?

Tags: water, refrigerator, ice

We bought a new fridge for our new home and the supply valve seems to have a 3/8" or 1/2" flare outlet (I'm unsure), while modern fridges appear to use a 1/4". I'm trying to figure out if I can cut one end of the supply line I bought on Amazon linked [HERE](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B01KAEN610) and use a compression sleeve (unsure on size) and another fitting (also unsure of size - is it really 3/8") to hook it up? I really appreciate the community's help!

[image]

Comment: measure carefully and consult a table of fitting sizes.  you may ber able to use an adjustable or fixed wrench to gauge the size of the outlet

Answer (score 1):

You could use a [water line tap](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B000I19AIE), [easily installed](https://www.ehow.com/how_2104184_tap-water-line.html).

That said, check local codes to see if it's allowed. Also note that these piercing taps may be more likely to leak, particularly on older, brittle, pipe.

Comment: I had this same thought later on after I posted.

Answer (score 1):

That flare fitting should un-screw from that tee. If it does, take it to a big box store (orange or blue)and show them that fitting. They will sell you what you need. You could replace that valve with a correct valve  that has the correct size tubing connection.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. You will need to go to a local store and buy only 2 items and it won’t cost you more than 10 dollars.

1. you will need: ADD-A-TEE) 3/8 in female comp x 3/8 in. OD comp x 1/4 in. OD comp.
2. you will need a 3/8-in cap and also a pipe tape.

The rest is just fitting the pieces together and tightening them well. Enjoy your new fridge.

Comment: Saddle valves (which is what I think you are referring to?) are common for this purpose but also trouble-prone. Their sole advantage is not needing any plumbing shill to install. If there's already a real threaded T, using that makes much more sense.